# Word for a person invited to a competition

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe a person who qualified to participate in an invitational competition (specifically an academic one), preferably with a particular emphasis on the "invited" part.

I've considered 'invitee,' but read that this is more of a legal term, and additionally it seems to me to have less of a focus on having to qualify for the invitation.

Example usage: "The ______(s) to the American Invitational Mathematics Exam were displeased by the poorly conducted contest after all the work they had put in to get that far."

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to ELU. It is required to provide an exemplary sentence where you would use the word. You can also have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Invitees

May be worth a second thought.

> One that is invited.

Usage isn't particularly related to the legal profession.

[free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/invitee)

e.g.

> "The invitees to the American Invitational Mathematics Exam were
> displeased by the poorly conducted contest after all the work they had
> put in to get that far."

In fact I have found it in use in exactly the type of context you are referring to:

> Blue MOP is for the second group of invitees and mostly consists of
> students who just completed their junior or sophomore year of high
> school, although in exceptional cases some 7th and 8th graders have
> participated.

Reference: [AOPS Wiki Mathematical Olympiad Summer Program](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Mathematical_Olympiad_Summer_Program)

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably be going with this one.  I'm not 100% sure why but it just felt off to me earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the word *guests* if I wanted to stress that they'd been invited. That might, however, take away from the fact that they qualified for it, presumably, on their own merit / qualities. *selected candidates* or *shortlisted candidates* might be more diplomatic since it indicates that they qualified and were thereby invited although it uses two words.

Comment: The OP does not say anything about any qualification. It could be a science competition for kids.

Comment: The situation I'm looking to use this in is pretty much a science competition for kids, but at a higher level (as in one would have to perform well in a previous round to receive an invitation to the next).

Comment: I'd imagine that counts as them having to qualify for the next round by performing well in the previous one @Heimar.

Comment: @AshwinNair You could use *italics* or **bold** instead of `code` to highlight those words. That is the preferred style on ELU. :)

Comment: @NVZ...Roger wilco.....habits from another site...now back to the matter at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Why not [**competitor**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20competitor)?

> an organization or country that is engaged in commercial or economic
>   competition with others.
>
> *"our main industrial competitors"*
>
> **synonyms:** rival, challenger, opponent, adversary; competition, opposition
>
> *"our European competitors"*
>
> a person who takes part in an athletic contest.
>
> **synonyms:** contestant, contender, challenger, participant, entrant; runner, player
>
> *"the competitors in the race"*

"The competitors in the American Invitational Mathematics Exam were displeased by the poorly conducted contest after all the work they had put in to get that far."

Comment: Seems like this has no implication of "invitation", which seems to be what the OP is specifically looking for.